# Get counter performance with powershell

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I am trying to get informations about iis requests, but when I try to get the counter performance with this :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_ASP_ActiveServerPages
```

I get the following error :

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid class
At line:1 char:21
+ $totob=Get-WmiObject <<<<  Win32_PerfRawData_ASP_ActiveServerPages
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for performance counter libraries to become corrupted and have to be rebuilt.

This KB article describes the process of rebuilding the counter libraries.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956

Answer (score 0):

First on wihch System are you experimenting this problem ?

Can you try :

```
Get-WMIObject -List| Where{$_.name -match "^Win32_.*_ASP.*"} | Sort Name | Format-Table name
```

Here is the result on my W2K8R2 server :

```
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASP_ActiveServerPages
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNET
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETAppsv2050727
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETv2050727
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319
Win32_PerfFormattedData_aspnetstate_ASPNETStateService
Win32_PerfRawData_ASP_ActiveServerPages
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETAppsv2050727
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETv2050727
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319
Win32_PerfRawData_aspnetstate_ASPNETStateService
```

Here is the result on my Window 8

```
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNET                                                                                     
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications                                                                         
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319                                                                  
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319                                                                      
Win32_PerfFormattedData_aspnetstate_ASPNETStateService                                                                    
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET                                                                                           
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications                                                                               
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319                                                                        
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319                                                                            
Win32_PerfRawData_aspnetstate_ASPNETStateService
```

Where the service W3SVC is not running.

Comment: I am on windows server 2008 r2 standard and this is what I get: